# Emacs lisp forward-sexp: Scan error: "Containing expression ends prematurely"

Tags: navigation

When writing Emacs Lisp code, I use `forward-sexp` (<kbd>C-M-right</kbd>) and `backward-sexp` (<kbd>C-M-left</kbd>) to navigate the buffer. However, in some cases these functions stops with error like:

> forward-sexp: Scan error: "Containing expression ends prematurely"

Here is an example:

```el
(defun my-test1()
  (message "ok1"))

(defun my-test2()
  (message "ok2"))
```

If cursor is on the first `(`, pressing <kbd>C-M-right</kbd> twice works fine. However, if cursor is on the first `d` (in `defun`), pressing <kbd>C-M-right</kbd> five times results in the error. Instead of the error, I would like to move further down the buffer to the next `defun` that is to the start of the line `(defun my-test2()`..

Comment: That's the behavior of `lispy-forward` and `lispy-backward` from https://github.com/abo-abo/lispy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hit `C-M-e` twice then `C-M-a` once to move to the beginning of the next `defun`, from *anywhere* in the current `defun` (those key bindings navigate across whole `defun`s).

Other than that, you probably want to get into Paredit (or SmartParens), for editing s-expressions. (The `C-M-f` of Paredit does not behave exactly the way you describe, but will skip the closing paren.) Read a short into and try to get the hang of Paredit; it will be immensely beneficial in the long run.

Comment: If you do this a lot you could wrap it as a command: `(defun next-defun () (interactive) (end-of-defun 2) (beginning-of-defun))`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `C-M-u` (`backward-up-list`) to move up a level of parentheses.

In your example, with point on the first `d`, you could use:

`C-M-u C-M-f C-M-f`

Or, if your instincts have you always hitting `C-M-f` first, you can go forward until you get the scan error; then go up, then go forward again.

Comment: Thanks @glucas. I tried `C-h m` when in `elisp-mode` but it only showed keys defined in `lisp-mode.el`. Typing `C-h k RET C-M-u` showed that `C-M-u` was defined in `lisp.el` (not `lisp-mode.el`).. so that was the reason I could not find the shortcuts myself.. How to get the other keyboard shortcuts (defined in `lisp.el`) ?

Comment: Hmm, you're right. With `C-h m` you get the list of keys in the current major mode map; but `C-M-u` is actually in the global map. You can use `C-h b` to see all the keys that are currently bound, although that can be a big list to search through...

Comment: By the way, you should take a look at the Emacs Manual section [Commands for Editing with Parentheses](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Parentheses.html) which covers this set of commands.